# cut sections of silence from audio

Tags: final-cut-pro

[image]

I've been going along a long audio clip, and using the blade <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> on either side of sections of silence, and then deleting the sections of silence.

Is there a way to automate this?

Delete sections of silence from the audio clip, leaving it as multiple discontiguous clips (but that all have at least some sound)?